# MemoryError when Using the read() Method in Reading a Large Size of JSON file from Amazon S3

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, etl, amazon-rds

I'm trying to import a large size of JSON FILE from Amazon S3 into AWS RDS-PostgreSQL using Python. But, these errors occured,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "my_code.py", line 67, in
>
> file_content = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(True)
>
> File "/home/user/asd-to-qwe/fgh-to-hjk/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/response.py", line 76, in read
>
> chunk = self._raw_stream.read(amt)
>
> File "/home/user/asd-to-qwe/fgh-to-hjk/env/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 239, in read
>
> data = self._fp.read()
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 462, in read
>
> s = self._safe_read(self.length)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 617, in _safe_read
>
> return b"".join(s)
>
> MemoryError

// my_code.py

```
import sys
import boto3
import psycopg2
import zipfile
import io
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=<aws_access_key_id>, aws_secret_access_key=<aws_secret_access_key>)
connection = psycopg2.connect(host=<host>, dbname=<dbname>, user=<user>, password=<password>)
cursor = connection.cursor()

bucket = sys.argv[1]
key = sys.argv[2]
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)

def insert_query(data):
    query = """
        INSERT INTO data_table
        SELECT
            (src.test->>'url')::varchar, (src.test->>'id')::bigint,
            (src.test->>'external_id')::bigint, (src.test->>'via')::jsonb
        FROM (SELECT CAST(%s AS JSONB) AS test) src
    """
    cursor.execute(query, (json.dumps(data),))


if key.endswith('.zip'):
    zip_files = obj['Body'].read()
    with io.BytesIO(zip_files) as zf:
        zf.seek(0)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zf, mode='r') as z:
            for filename in z.namelist():
                with z.open(filename) as f:
                    for line in f:
                        insert_query(json.loads(line.decode('utf-8')))
if key.endswith('.json'):
    file_content = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(True)
    for line in file_content:
        insert_query(json.loads(line))


connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Are there any solutions to these problems? Any help would do, thank you so much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Large Size of Zipped JSON File from Amazon S3 into AWS RDS-PostgreSQL Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51549272/importing-large-size-of-zipped-json-file-from-amazon-s3-into-aws-rds-postgresql)

Comment: The Zipped File is the problem in there. But in here, it's the JSON File. The method read() is the problem when reading the JSON file, I always get the Memory Error. Is there anymore ways to read the JSON file? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A significant savings can be had by avoiding slurping your whole input file into memory as a `list` of lines.

Specifically, these lines are terrible on memory usage, in that they involve a peak memory usage of a `bytes` object the size of your whole file, plus a `list` of lines with the complete contents of the file as well:

```py
file_content = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(True)
for line in file_content:
```

For a 1 GB ASCII text file with 5 million lines, on 64 bit Python 3.3+, that's a peak memory requirement of roughly 2.3 GB for *just* the `bytes` object, the `list`, and the individual `str`s in the `list`. A program that needs 2.3x as much RAM as the size of the files it processes won't scale to large files.

To fix, change that original code to:

```py
file_content = io.TextIOWrapper(obj['Body'], encoding='utf-8')
for line in file_content:
```

Given that [`obj['Body']` appears to be usable for lazy streaming](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html?highlight=get_object#S3.Client.get_object) this should remove *both* copies of the complete file data from memory. Using `TextIOWrapper` means `obj['Body']` is lazily read and decoded in chunks (of a few KB at a time), and the lines are iterated lazily as well; this reduces memory demands to a small, largely fixed amount (the peak memory cost would depend on the length of the longest line), regardless of file size.

**Update:**

It looks like `StreamingBody` doesn't implement the `io.BufferedIOBase` ABC. It does have [its own documented API](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/response.html) though, that can be used for a similar purpose. If you can't make the `TextIOWrapper` do the work for you (it's much more efficient and simple if it can be made to work), an alternative would be to do:

```py
file_content = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in obj['Body'].iter_lines())
for line in file_content:
```

Unlike using `TextIOWrapper`, it doesn't benefit from bulk decoding of blocks (each line is decoded individually), but otherwise it should still achieve the same benefits in terms of reduced memory usage.

Comment: It's raising an error. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "my_code.py", line 67, in <module>
file_content = io.TextIOWrapper(obj['Body'], encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'StreamingBody' object has no attribute 'readable'

Comment: @GeraldMilan: Ugh. They made a kinda file-like object that isn't actually compatible with [the `io` ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#class-hierarchy). You could wrap the `StreamingBody` in a simple file-like class that implemented [the `BufferedIOBase` ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedIOBase), or if it's already really close to what you need, monkey-patch in the necessary stuff (e.g. `obj['Body'].readable = True` to set that specific attribute).

Comment: @GeraldMilan: If that doesn't work, or it's too complicated, I updated the answer to provide an alternative that works with [the `StreamingBody` API](https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/response.html).