# How to read large JSON file from Amazon S3 using Boto3

Tags: json, amazon-s3, etl, boto3

I am trying to read a JSON file from Amazon S3 and its file size is about 2GB. When I use the method `.read()`, it gives me `MemoryError`.

Are there any solutions to this problem? Any help would do, thank you so much!

Comment: What is your using platform ? I guess you run the program on AWS Lambda. Please write platform detail, and purpose of reading JSON. Then I can suggest something.

Comment: Here's the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51587726/importing-large-size-of-json-file-from-amazon-s3-into-aws-rds-postgresql-using-p

Comment: Could you download the file and then process it locally?

Comment: Check the answer, it's now solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I found a way which worked for me efficiently. I had 1.60 GB file and need to load for processing.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=<aws_access_key_id>, aws_secret_access_key=<aws_secret_access_key>)

# Now we collected data in the form of bytes array.
data_in_bytes = s3.Object(bucket_name, filename).get()['Body'].read()

#Decode it in 'utf-8' format
decoded_data = data_in_bytes.decode('utf-8')

#I used io module for creating a StringIO object.
stringio_data = io.StringIO(decoded_data)

#Now just read the StringIO obj line by line.
data = stringio_data.readlines()

#Its time to use json module now.
json_data = list(map(json.loads, data))
```

So `json_data` is the content of the file. I know there are lots of variable manipulations, but it worked for me.

Comment: I will be getting "memoryError" on the line of " stringio_data = io.StringIO(decoded_data)" Any suggestion to resolve this. ( while reading a JSON file)?

Comment: Still get a memory error with this one. vaquar khan's answer works.

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over the object.

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=<aws_access_key_id>, aws_secret_access_key=<aws_secret_access_key>)
fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket_name', Key='key')
for row in fileObj["body"]:
    line = row.decode('utf-8')
    print(json.loads(line))
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem. Here's the code. Hope it helps for future use!

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=<aws_access_key_id>, aws_secret_access_key=<aws_secret_access_key>)
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket_name', Key='key')
data = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in obj['Body'].iter_lines())
    for row in file_content:
        print(json.loads(row))
```

Comment: where is file_content coming from?

Answer (score 1):

```
import json
import boto3



def lambda_handler(event, context):

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    #reading all s3 bucket
    for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
        print(bucket.name)

        json_data=json.loads(s3.Object("vkhan-s3-bucket", "config/sandbox/config.json").get()['Body'].read().decode())

        print(json_data)

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(json_data)
    }
```